# Why people use BufferedReader to read post data

Tags: java, http, servlets

People sometimes use BufferedReader to read post data.

```
    BufferedReader bReader;
    String postData = null;
    try {
        bReader = request.getReader();
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        int len;
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((len = bReader.read(buf)) != -1) {
            sBuilder.append(buf, 0, len);
        }
        postData = sBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        bReader = null;
    }
```

When should I use this to get parameter, how about request.getParameter()?

Comment: I suggest processing the text as you read it, rather than copying the data from one buffer, to another buffer and processing that. It is more efficient and makes the code cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As EJP notes, this approach is used when the request's POST data consists of something other than request parameters.

So ...

> When should I use this to get parameter, how about request.getParameter()?

You use it when you are *expecting* the request POST body to be a document.  But it may not be adequate, as explained below.

---

That code is not particularly efficient, and that it *could* be problematic in other respects.

On the efficiency side, the code is using a `BufferedReader` *AND* reading into a large(-ish) character buffer before transferring into a `StringBuilder`.

- Using a `BufferedReader` and a `char[]` is kind of pointless.  If you are going to do block reads, it is (marginally) better to read from the underlying `Reader`.
- Reading the entire POST data into a `StringBuilder` (without limiting its length) could leave you open to denial of service attacks aimed at triggering OOMEs.  (You will get the same problem if the long requests are legitimate ...).

There are also larger issues:

- Should process the POST data as a character stream rather trying to create a single String?
- Is it correct to treat the POST data as characters at all?  (See the Content-type header.)
- Are you using the correct encoding scheme to decode the characters? (See the Content-type header, etcetera)
- Should you be using the using the Content-length header to as a hint for sizing things and/or enforcing request size limits.

In short, the code that you are asking us about looks to be too simplistic to be a general solution to the problem of reading POST data.

---

> If the post data cost lots of memory, will it be sent into two parts or more?

Probably not.  Indeed, unless you (the developer of the webapp) implement a scheme which allows the client side to send in smaller chunks, the client may have no choice but to send one big document in the POST data.  Of course, depending on what the document is and how it needs to be processed, you may not *need* to assemble it all in memory.   The other point is that you should not rely on the client "doing the right thing" in terms of what it sends you.  Your server needs to *defend itself* at some point.

Comment: Very good, +1, but BufferedReader transfers straight to the target buffer under some circumstances, so '(marginally) better' ain't necessarily so.

Comment: @EJP - The marginal efficiency improvement includes the cost of instantiating the unnecessary `BufferedReader`.  Ergo there is a difference in all circumstances.

Comment: Off topic, but congratulations on passing 200000 rep recently `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes POST data isn't name-value pairs. Sometimes for example it is an XML document.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about BufferedReader, but you could try creating an ArrayList of Strings and each time a post is sent shove the message into the array and give a limit on the index size otherwise you will end up with a memory problem depending on the harddrive space of the designated server.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I want to ask. If the post data cost lots of memory, will it be sent into two parts or more?

Comment: If you are talking about the amount of load the ArrayList has you can limit the total number of String objects in the arraylist simply by checking the size to see if it is your determined amount and if it is remove the first index and continue to add each time.